# Wagtail - How To Remove Sub-Menu Items From Settings Menu

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Wagtail includes a "settings" menu item by default, with some default settings items, such as "sites" and "redirects".

I know that you can register a new setting with the `register_setting` decorator, and that various hooks are available for customizing the top level menu items, but not sub-menu items. How can I REMOVE (or hide the display of) the default settings items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Wagtail group (Groups under the Settings menu).  When assigning object permissions for the group, make sure Site Settings is not selected.  Then assign to the group the Users who you do not want to be able to see the Site Settings menu, and it will not show up for them.

Comment: I would prefer to be able to manage this programmatically, but this is the accepted way to accomplish the goal at hand.

Comment: Well, it would be pretty hackish, but you could include custom css and set `display: none` on the Settings `<li>` (but I wouldn't advise it):  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/hooks.html#editor-interface.  The Groups/permission settings are very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

the solution has been explained here in this [website](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-remove-a-menu-item-from-wagtail-settings-menu/)
if we want to delete the user from the settings menu item

```py
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_settings_menu')
def hide_user_menu_item(request, menu_items):
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'user']
```

for main menu if we want to delete Images from the main menu item

```py
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_main_menu')
def hide_images_menu_item(request, menu_items):
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'images']
```

**For higher Wagtail6.0**

hooks are now imported differently

```
from wagtail import hooks
```